# How to execute python script from tcl script with argument

Tags: python-3.x, tcl, parameter-passing

I have the following tcl script:

```
puts "The total number of arguments is $argc"
if {$argc > 0} {puts "The arguments in ARGV are: $argv" }
exec python  $argv/../scripts/sim/sim_comp_gen.py
```

How can I exec the python script ans pass it the $argv?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `{*}` syntax is key here:

```
exec python ../scripts/sim/sim_comp_gen.py {*}$argv
```

If you're making it relative to the name of the script, that's in `$argv0` and Tcl has some built-in utilities for making that easier:

```
set script [file join [file dirname $argv0] scripts/sim/sim_comp_gen.py]
exec python $script {*}$argv
```

You *might* need `file nativename` on Windows. (I can't remember if python does the slash-type ignoring/conversion.)

```
set script [file join [file dirname $argv0] scripts/sim/sim_comp_gen.py]
exec python [file nativename $script] {*}$argv
```

---

On a very old version of Tcl that doesn't support `{*}`? Use `eval` *carefully*…

```
set script [file join [file dirname $argv0] scripts/sim/sim_comp_gen.py]
eval [list exec python $script] $argv
```

The key is to use `list` to de-fang things. That works even when you've got tricky things like spaces in filenames.

Answer (score 1):

Donal's solution is the best. 
You can try out below as well.

```
exec echo "python_script_name.py argument1 argument2" > ./tempfile
exec chmod +x ./tempfile
exec ./tempfile
```

Let me know if it works.